# Is there a way to download/stream videos in a lower quality than the original file?

Tags: video, streaming

When I try to stream videos (mainly *torrent* videos) they always are in high quality (720p at least). I don't have enough internet bandwidth to do a smooth stream, so I need to download the entirely to watch it.

Is there anyway that I can take videos (*torrent* or direct link) that are in high quality and download lower pixels per frame content? If so, is it also possible to select only part of that file to have a lower quality?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot download parts to reassemble, of a normal video download that is only encoded in one res, or a stream that has only one res available.  The files are compressed/encoded/animated and pulling down parts and pieces of the whole would just be a jumbled up mess.  It would have to be decoded first, (in most cases) then parts of the whole could be resized using a quick line method, which would require something having the whole to decode first.

I think there are some online locations that would convert for you, where you can provide the link , instead of the upload.  They are classed as "Online Video Converters"  I doubt any exist that would want to do torrents, and they may charge for the services.

---

Other Stuff that is not within the scope of the question your asking:

Even frames of most video encodes could not be downloaded seperate to have a reduced frame rate (and therfore less download) because the frames are animated, dependant on the previous frames, and only able to be decoded with the keyframe and subsequent frames that the frames are built from.

There have been streams and video encode methods invented that do work along these lines, providing different people a range of possible resolutions and dowload quantity to be streaming, even within the same broadcast stream.

There are often many possible streams available as seperate files at locations that provide streaming online that can be selected, or are selected for you,  like at Youtube.

Sometimes lower qualities and sizes of things are also available different to the user when using thier mobile version of a site. You can try same sites with a mobile phone to see if the site has a different mobile site name, or acts different when there it a mobile agent string used to access the site. Many desktop browsers can have the browser agent string then changed , in an attempt to fake the site into thinking your on a mobile device.
So in an attempt to find reduced versions find the address name of thier mobile, or possibly adjust a desktop agent string to fake it is mobile.

Comment: Yes but tecnically we can get individual frames, because you can change the position of the video in YouTube - obviously it would check for previous frames to construct the actual frame.

But there is no such file format that uses something like [progressive jpgs](http://blog.patrickmeenan.com/2013/06/progressive-jpegs-ftw.html) and loading the frames with dynamic quality?

Comment: In the case of youtube , jumping frames is based like any other player would do it, it rebuilds from the keyframe up, buffers holding it or the whole uncompressed section somewhere.  And yes there were streaming methods invented where it was akin to progressive.